# angularjs ng-repeat renders after for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

It does not matter how large your `for` loop is, AngularJS doesn't render anything to HTML unless the loop has finished. But it should render to HTML as `$scope` changes (as happens in two-way data binding). A [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmpwBY) is created for this.

Have I misunderstood anything?

Comment: I think because all static code inside controller executes synchronously, and then $scope.$apply fires, so it is the reason why you have all 20 items at once.

Comment: I think is that for angular version. see this sample with version 1.6.1 http://plnkr.co/edit/un6G6SATEiSKWNqlKHgy?p=preview

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed No, it doesn't. See with more data. about 50000. http://plnkr.co/edit/CwcWojGxkH00iCkreLYp?p=preview

Comment: consider this point that angular digest cycle is 10.  if you loop less than 10 it's work correctly. http://plnkr.co/edit/ECprLVJjoeHt8cfouImJ?p=preview

Comment: @Leguest Good idea. Reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force re-render manually with `$timeout`, see codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWNmap - it's important that separated function was created due to asynchronous `$timeout` `i` always has 20 value because of  JS closure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/3368498 But this behavior is OK, angular re-render when it starts digest cycle - and if it will start with any change, it will be crazy slow. All in all, you can think about it as you wrote, when 2-way binding change it is re-rendered - cases when this behavior matches are very rare.